# Angular 4/5 getting route id from JSON

Tags: json, angular, angular5

I am new at Angular so I need your help. I am trying to get an ID for every user I click on from my data.json list of users. So I have my list of users, and when I click on any one of them it opens a new page with router, witch works fine, and I can get a ID of that user, but I can't access his name, age and other informations to show on screen, just ID.

**component**

```
user: any[];

constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private usersService: UsersService) {

let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
if(id) this.usersService.getUsers(id).subscribe(user => this.user = user);}
```

The thing is that I don't have `getUsers(id)` function in my service, because I don't know how to get ID from json data file. And I need your help to make that function.

**data.json**

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Paul",
  "surname": "Crowe",
  "age": 28,
  "gender": "male",
  "friends": [
    2
  ]
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Rob",
  "surname": "Fitz",
  "age": 23,
  "gender": "male",
  "friends": [
    1,
    3
  ]
 } ...
]
```

**Service**

```
 getUsers() {
 return this.http.get('./assets/data.json').map(array => array);
 }
```

This getUsers is not good I think for taking ID. So I need help with that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use have to use this keyword e.g : this.id

Comment: a bit unclear whar you want,..

Comment: A real-world application would have a different rest service returning **the** user identified by the given ID, instead of forcing you to get all the users. If really this is not possible, use Array.find() to find the user among the array of users. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. I updated the topic.

Comment: Yeah, I just have data.json file that I need to use in my project. And with that file I need to loop through users and get info on every user I click on.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you want something like:

```
user: any;

constructor(
private route: ActivatedRoute, 
private usersService: UsersService) {
 let id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if(id) this.usersService.getUsers().subscribe(users =>
              this.user = users.getById(id);}
 }

private getUserById(userId: number){
     return this.users.filter(u=>u.id===userId);
 }
```

Comment: I'd also recommend to implement ngOnInit and call getUsers function there.

Comment: Property 'getById' does not exist on type 'Response'. -error. I tried changing it to getUserById but it still gives me an error. And for that getUsers function, I don't have that function because I don't know how to access 'assets/data.json' file. It's there just as a placeholder. So If you know how to get that Id from json from using that function it would be awesome. Something like ' getUsers() { this.http.get('./assets/data.json') } but don't know how

Comment: sorry, it should be  this.users = users;this.user = getById(id);

Answer (score -1):

Use this.id

```
if(this.id){
 this.usersService.getUsers(this.id).subscribe(user => this.user = user);}
}
```

**EDIT**

```js
var users = [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "Paul",
  "surname": "Crowe",
  "age": 28,
  "gender": "male",
  "friends": [
    2
  ]
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Rob",
  "surname": "Fitz",
  "age": 23,
  "gender": "male",
  "friends": [
    1,
    3
  ]
 }  
];

const user = users.find(t=>t.id ==1);
console.log(user);
```

Comment: The thing is that I don't have that getUsers() func. because I don't know how to get ID from that json data.

Comment: since you already have JSON, you just need to use array.filter or find

Comment: Yeah. I can't change anything in data.json file, because it's part of the test.  So I have to use it like that and find id of the clicked user so I can access his data (name, age, gender...)

Comment: so you can do as above suggested

Comment: Yeah filter may work, but I am still new at this, so where should I use find function, because in my service I don't have any connection to data.json, witch is my main problem, I don't know how to access it and then when I access it I can try to get the ID

Comment: In your service, instead of returning an Observable<Array<User>>, you want to return an Observable<User>. So you need to use the RxJS map operator to transform the array into a single user: `return this.http.get<Array<User>>('data.json').map(array => array.find(u => u.id === userId));`